# Why I cannot load the CSS file and JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I'm beginner for developing the website. Would someone help me to solve these problems? The directory for the file is correct but don't know why I'm still getting the error. Wordpress cannot load the CSS file as well as the JavaScript.
I have used two techniques but still cannot work which can be shown as below:
Anyone can teach me why I cannot load CSS file and Javascript file although using these techniques.

First Technique that I used is `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> and <?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>`

Header.php

```
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
        <script>
            var template_dir_js = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>";
        </script>
            <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/skel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/skel-layers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->    
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-desktop.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-mobile.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-1000px.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/skel.css" />

    </head>
```

Second Technique that I used is wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style

Header.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <?wp_head();?>
</head>
```

Footer.php

```
    ...
<?php wp_footer();?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Functions.php

```
<?php

function wpt_theme_styles() {   
wp_enqueue_style('abs',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/font-awesome.min.css',array(),'1.0.0','all'); 
wp_enqueue_style('foundation_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css',array(),'1.0.0','all'); 
wp_enqueue_style('normali_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-1000px.css',array(),'1.0.0','all');
wp_enqueue_style('normalze1_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-mobile.css',array(),'1.0.0','all');
wp_enqueue_style('normalze_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-desktop.css',array(),'1.0.0','all');
wp_enqueue_style('main_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/skel.css',array(),'1.0.0','all'); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'init_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/skel.min.js', array(),'1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'init1_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/skel-layers.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'init2_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/init.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );    

wp_enqueue_style('abs');
wp_enqueue_style('foundation_css');
wp_enqueue_style('normali_css');
wp_enqueue_style('foundation_css');
wp_enqueue_style('foundation_css');
wp_enqueue_style('foundation_css');
wp_enqueue_script('modernizr_js');
wp_enqueue_script('foundation_js');
wp_enqueue_script('normalze1_css');
wp_enqueue_script('normalze_css');
wp_enqueue_script('main_css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_theme_styles'); 
?>
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDuLm.jpg)
[File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BND7i.jpg)

When I view the source

```
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/js/skel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/js/skel-layers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/css/style-desktop.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/css/style-mobile.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/css/style-1000px.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/momentum/css/skel.css" />
```

that means the URL is correct

Comment: Use view source to see the URLs WordPress is creating.

Comment: @user2182349 the URL is correct but still got error

Comment: Are the files there?

Comment: What does the net-tab in dev-console tell you? Are you getting any errors, 404s, other non-200 return codes?

Comment: @user2182349 yes you can check the images that I upload, name is "File Directory"

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie do you mean Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)?

Comment: If you paste the URL of a CSS file in the address bar of the browser, do you see the CSS file or a 404?

Comment: That "resource not found" would be a good place to start, yes.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie How should I do next step?

Comment: @user2182349 let me try first

Comment: @user2182349 cannot load the CSS file same as before

Answer (score 0):

i use the following configuration:

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
...
...
<link href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/myjs.js"></script>
...
...
<?php
/* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
 * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
 * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
 * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
 */
wp_head();
?>
</head>
<div class="myheader">
...
...
</div>
```

index.php (or page.php, single.php, etc...)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="mycontainer">
....
....
....
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

footer.php

```
<div class="myfooter">
...
...
...
</div>
<?php
    /* Always have wp_footer() just before the closing </body>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to reference JavaScript files.
     */

    wp_footer();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

im not using anything in `functions.php` to do this, just in the required files